# Discord.js removerole not a function

Tags: discord.js

person.removerole(mainrole.id);
            person.addrole(muterole.id);

```
        message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`);

        setTimeout(function(){
            person.addrole(mainrole.id);
            person.removerole(muterole.id);
            message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted!`)
        }, ms(time));
```

Answer (score 1):

`addrole()` and `removerole()` are not valid.

Use [`roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) and [`roles.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove)